# Going on planned vacation before starting possible new job

Tags: job-offer, internship, fulltime

So I had an internship over the summer at a bank, which extended into the final semester of my master's program. I will be done with my finals in a few weeks and my internship will finish around the same time. My boss spoke to me today about full time opportunities and mentioned he will only be giving a full time offer to 1 intern. (there are 2 of us)

The situation is that I had planned a trip to see my family back in my home country for 5 weeks as I haven't seen them in several years and to get a breather. Is there anyway to communicate/negotiate with my boss regarding this issue?

Would appreciate any advice and thanks!

Comment: Whatever you decide to do, make sure that if you're offered the job, you negotiate those 5 weeks as part of the offer. Ideally get it in writing as part of the offer details/letter/contract. You wouldn't be the first to be stuck in a conflict between a boss promising something in an interview and HR refusing to budge on vacation policies. (Assuming this holiday would take place *after* you've started working.)

Comment: Kris, there's a pending edit from user [@rayven1lk](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/44361/rayven1lk). If this is you, please log in under your original account to make changes to your post. If you need help merging your two accounts, check out our [Help Center Page](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Answer (score 11):

Just tell him, it's fairly normal in your situation for people to take a break before joining the workforce full time. You're only looking at 5 weeks, many people take a year off. Employers understand this.

It shouldn't affect your chances too much. So if you want the full time position, let him know when you would be able to commence work and then relax and enjoy your well earned break before you hit the rat race.

Comment: I agree. The key point is to have your full-time work relationship start after you come back, so it's not actual vacation time. And that is fairly normal.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely your boss already made up his mind on whether he will be offering the full time job to you or not. If he plans to offer it to you, then it shouldn't matter if you take time off (per comments above, do so before you start the job).

If your boss's decision about you will be impacted by your request for time off, then I am not sure how committed he is to you. If he is trying to play you off the other intern to see who will suck up or work extra hard to please him more, then it is likely that such blackmail behavior will continue into the full-time job. In which case the cost/benefit of this opportunity is debatable.

To answer your specific question, I would recommend to have an honest chat with your boss: "Hi ___, I wanted to ask your feedback on something. I have been planning to visit my family abroad for a duration of 5 weeks. I have not seen them since I began studies here. The time between graduation and a potential full-time job seems like the most appropriate time for this trip. So I wanted to let you know of my plans, and see whether you are OK with this or if this might cause any issues for the timing of the internship as well as the opportunity for a full-time position with this company."

To be safe, I recommend approaching him face-to-face rather than by email (face-to-face interaction makes refusals harder). Do this as soon as possible to give him enough advance notice before your departure.

If the boss makes a pretty big deal about this and shows that this is kind of a problem, this is a signal that this person might be difficult to negotiate with regarding time off in the future as well, and will signal that you might want to reconsider the full-time opportunity with this firm. If he is amicable and consents without making a fuss, this is probably a good sign that he likes you and would be agreeable for similar requests in the future. Good luck!

Comment: I agree. But would add I don't think you should bring it up until you are offered the position. It COULD mean they choose the other intern (because they could start sooner). Otherwise, this is really normal. Most of our interns have taken several month long trips abroad or at least a month long vacation in country before they started full time. We encourage it because you generally don't get the opportunity after you start full time for something like that.